# Convertir tipo de dato varhcar a datetime en SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server-2012

Me están compartiendo información la cual tengo que agregar a una tabla, el problema es que la fecha me la envían en este formato 11012019 que seria 11/01/2019

No se si es posible realizar este proceso pero, esto es como me imagino que puede ser:

```
SELECT 
CONVERT(DATETIME,'11012019',103) AS FECHA
FROM ORIGINA
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema está en que el valor de la fecha la obtienes sin ningún delimitador, y hasta donde tengo entendido no hay manera de que eso sea interpretado como una fecha, al menos que tenga el siguiente formato **`YYYYMMDD`** el cual también es un formato estándar, el [ISO 8601](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

En tu caso lo mas que se me ocurre es fraccionar ese valor y convertirlo en un formato estándar **`YYYYMMDD`**.

Te dejo un ejemplo utilizando ***substring***:

```
SELECT 
CONVERT(
  DATE,
  SUBSTRING('11012019',5,4) + SUBSTRING('11012019',3,2) + SUBSTRING('11012019',1,2)
);
```

Y acá otro ejemplo utilizando ***stuff***:

```
SELECT
CONVERT(
  DATE,
  STUFF(STUFF('11012019', 5, 0, '/'), 3, 0, '/'),
  103  -- DD/MM/YYYY
);
```

> [SUBSTRING](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql): La función SUBSTRING le permiten extraer una subcadena
>   de una cadena (Devuelve parte de una expresión de caracteres).
>
> [STUFF](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/stuff-transact-sql): La función STUFF inserta una cadena en otra. Elimina una
>   longitud determinada de caracteres de la primera cadena a partir de la
>   posición de inicio y, a continuación, inserta la segunda cadena en la
>   primera, en la posición de inicio.

Answer (score 1):

Reemplaza **DATETIME** por **VARCHAR(255)**

```
SELECT CONVERT (VARCHAR(255),'11012019',103) AS FECHA
```

Con **DATETIME** sería así:

```
SELECT CONVERT (DATETIME,'11/01/2019',103) AS FECHA
```

Y con **DATE**:

```
SELECT CONVERT (DATE,'11/01/2019',103) AS FECHA
```

> Ahora que si necesitas utilizar forzosamente en ese orden la cadena recibida, te funcionará de la siguiente manera:

```
DECLARE @date VARCHAR(8);
DECLARE @year VARCHAR(4);
DECLARE @month VARCHAR(2);
DECLARE @day VARCHAR(2);

SET @date = '11012019';
SET @day = (SELECT SUBSTRING(@date,0,3));
SET @month = (SELECT SUBSTRING(@date,3,2));
SET @year = (SELECT SUBSTRING(@date,5,5));
SET @date = @year + @month + @day;

SELECT CONVERT(DATE,@date,103) AS FECHA
```

> Para obtener **11/01/2019** cómo lo indicas en tú último comentario:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),CONVERT(DATE,@date),103) AS FECHA
```

Comment: El resultado sigue siendo el mismo, el resultado es '11012019'

Comment: Agregue más ejemplos a la respuesta. ;)

Comment: Creo que no me explique bien, lo que necesito es que este número '11012019' se convierta en esto '11/01/2019'

Comment: Perfecto, agregue a la respuesta la consulta para obtener 11/01/2019 cómo mencionas.